# Ionic2 ionic-cloud notifications on android

Tags: push-notification, notifications, ionic2, android-notifications, ionic-cloud

On Android. When app is closed and I click on notification, the app opens but the notification does not call the desired function. Why? i tried a lot of things, that didn't help...

simplified code:

frontend settings:

```
const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
'core': {
    'app_id': '61d7358c'
},
'push': {
    'sender_id': '1077211678670',
    'pluginConfig': {
        'ios': {
            'alert': true,
            'badge': false,
            'sound': true,
            'clearBadge': true
        },
        'android': {
            'iconColor': '#1BB6EB',
            'sound': true,
            'clearBadge': true, 
            'clearNotifications': false,
            'forceShow': true 
        }
    }
}};
```

subscribe on even:

```
ngOnInit() { this.push.plugin.on('notification', data => this.notificationEvent(data)); }
```

function:

```
notificationEvent(data) { console.log('data', data) }
```

backend:

```
axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${config.integrations.ionic.token}`
                },
                data
            });
```

data:

```
{ profile: 'devit1',
  notification:
    { title: 'new entry',
      message: 'new entry',
      payload:
         { type: 1,
           entryId: 2020,
           id: 4191,
           notId: 4191,
           title: 'newEntry',
           message: 'new entry,  },
      ios:
         { title: 'new entry',
           message: 'new entry',
           content_available: 0,
           sound: 'default' },
      android:
         { title: 'new entry',
           message: 'new entry',
           content_available: 0,
           sound: 'default' } 
  },
  tokens: [ 'fZ4_yY:APA91bFYxyT2gsqYvMPfwFYNJVXBwTFkk73-eohDQ_m-f_wfCiJWtUaIazG39' ] }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see whether you can improve your question to be more likely to be answered.